# Use JSON.net to parse json string

Tags: c#, ios, json, xamarin

I am using xamarin and c# and this is my first project using these. So kindly bear with me if this is a very basic question.

I have getting a JSON response from my server and I am trying to store these values in a class. I couldn't figure out how to do that in Csharp using JSON.Net

Here is my code :

OfferClass.cs

```
namespace TestApp_IOS_2
{
    public class OfferClass
    {
        public OfferClass ()
        {
        }

        private String title;

        public String getTitle ()
        {
            return title;
        }

        public void setTitle (String title)
        {
            this.title = title;
        }
    }
}
```

ViewDidLoad Method :

```
public override void ViewDidLoad ()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad ();

    // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    String jsonResponse = GetResponse ();

    Console.WriteLine ("Response : " + jsonResponse);
    this.textFieldResponse.Text = jsonResponse; 

    parseResponse (jsonResponse);
}
```

GetResponse Method :

```
public String GetResponse()
{

    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    try {
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream()) {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8);
            return reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
    catch (WebException ex) {
        WebResponse errorResponse = ex.Response;
        using (Stream responseStream = errorResponse.GetResponseStream())
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8"));
            String errorText = reader.ReadToEnd();
            Console.WriteLine ("error : "+errorText);
        }
        throw;
    }

}
```

}

ParseResponse Method :

```
public void parseResponse(String jsonResponse)
{
    OfferClass offer = new OfferClass ();

    //String output = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject (offer);
    //Console.WriteLine ("Output : " + output);

    offer = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OfferClass> (jsonResponse);

    Console.WriteLine ("Offer Title : " + offer.getTitle());
}
```

Here is the exception that i am getting :

```
Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'TestApp_IOS_2.OfferClass' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List<T> that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.
Path '', line 3, position 2.
```

I understand what the error says, that Deserialize needs a JSON Object, but how to do that, is what is puzzling me.

EDIT :::

My JSON Example

```
{
"id":"138",
"coupon_title":"",
"coupon_image":null,
"owner_id":"181",
"title":"killer campaign",
"desc":"as",
"category_id":"49",
"active":"1",
"campaign_type":"Store Based",
"st_date":"2014-04-09 12:23:14",
"end_date":"2014-03-26 00:00:00",
"template_id":"0",
"campaign_template_title":"",
"template_title":"",
"campaign_template_id":null,
"campaign_offer":"reward",
"logo":"\/assets\/admin\/img\/thumb.jpg",
"status":"published",
"radius":"1.00",
"date_created":"0000-00-00 00:00:00",
"coupon_barcode":"",
"tinyurl":"http:\/\/is.gd\/gYthYp",
"location":"My Store",
"city":"Secunderabad",
"state_id":"3689",
"address_1":"Marredpally, Ranga Reddy, ",
"address_2":"Hyderabad",
"indoor_mall_location":"",
"zip":"500026",
"latitude":"17.4443717",
"longitude":"78.518472100",
"distance":0,
"link":"\/app\/rendersplash\/138\/cm\/23456789",
"reward_link":"\/app\/previewreward\/138\/23456789",
"return_to_offers_link":"\/app\/offers\/500026\/17.4435394\/78.5026527\/5\/json\/23456789"
}
```

Comment: What does your JSON look like?  The error seems to be saying that you are trying to deserialize an array of objects into a single object.  Additionally, OfferClass has no public properties.  JSON.Net is not going to understand that setTitle() and getTitle() map to a "Title" property.

Comment: @Jason, edited my question. Please look at it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `OfferClass` needs to be more C# friendly:

```
public class OfferClass
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    // And so on... to match the JSON
}
```

Also, I think your JSON is actually an array. You have listed a single example, but I think it might be returning an array of similar items. You will need to Deserialize into an array or `List<OfferClass>`.

Comment: Ok.. will give it a try.. will get back to you

Comment: Thanks, used this... List<OfferClass> offers = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<OfferClass>> (jsonResponse);

Answer (score 1):

Generate your class from your JSON using this tool

http://json2csharp.com/